# How to monitor if network is under pressure in linux?

Tags: linux, networking, bash

How can I monitor a linux server and see its network is under pressure, for instance, not enougth bandwidth and so on, so I can get notice?

Comment: Setup a Nagios / Grafana / Prometheus or other monitoring solution and check the relevant metrics depending on what you want to be alerted for.

Comment: Is there any simpler way? I don't need gui or many advance figures. I just want to get notice when network is under heavy load.

Comment: Check the /proc network information for the information you want to be notified of?

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking into `/sys/class/net/$dev/statistics` or `/proc/net/` but honestly you will have to spend a lot of time searching for the metric you need and then elaborate a complex script to do some math and alert you whenever you need.

You're reinventing the wheel essentially, you're looking for an easy way and the easiest is to setup a system that was created for this scope like Ginnungagap mentioned, it's way easier to setup a threshold and an email address for getting the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `iftop` to see network usage in linux.

Cent OS `yum install iftop`

Ubuntu `apt-get install iftop`